# Image loading is slow when selecting it from gallery

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I'm working on an application where the user upload his picture either through camera or by selecting image from the gallery while registration. It works fine on some of the devices but when the image size is huge it gets slow as it takes time to load in image view. Is there a way to fix default size of the image irrespective of the devices. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the size of the image?

Comment: please try to reduce image with bitmap factory and use any third party library so it will help you. like Picaso, Aquery, ImageLoader

Comment: try to use any media picker library that cover all scenario

Comment: yeah i tried to reduce the image size... should I try loading it with Picasso or something? I was using imageView.setImageBitmap(image)